# Definition of Borel measure from Rudin's book

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

What means "$\sigma$-*algebra of all Borel sets*" in this context?

Is it Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{B}(X)$ or any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ containing $\mathfrak{B}(X)$?

Comment: If there is some topology then the connected Borel-$\sigma$ algebra is the **smallest** $\sigma$-algebra that contains all open sets.

Comment: @drhab, What means here "connected"?

Comment: Every topology induces a Borel $\sigma$-algebra: the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the topology. So every topology is connected in that way with a  Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @drhab, But I guess that I didn't get answer to my question."$\sigma$-algebra of all Borel sets" it is the same as Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Yes. You can only speak of Borel-sets if a topology is involved.

Comment: @drhab, Why we can't talk about any sigma-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ which contains $\mathfrak{B}(X)$?

Comment: Which one then? If that's not clear then the definition cannot be recognized as a definition. It speaks of **the** $\sigma$-algebra of all Borelsets.

Comment: @drhab, The problem is the following: Before i always met the notion "Borel sigma-algebra" but I have never seen "sigma-algebra of Borel sets". As you said they are the same. Right?

Comment: Indeed. As I said they are the same. If you ever encounter something that contradicts me in this, then please let me know. I have good trust that that will never happen, but must be cautious of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41601/discussion-between-rfz-and-drhab).

Comment: Good question.  Surely one can consider a $\sigma$-algebra which includes the Borel  $\sigma$-algebra. HOWEVER, when Rudin writes "THE $\sigma$-algebra of all Borel sets" he means the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, not a larger $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Ramiro, Yes I also supposed that it's an interesting question! Thanks for information!